# How can I add a profile tab with the viewed users nodes?

Tags: views, users

I have tried using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) so far to create a tab in the users profile to display a list of the nodes created by that very author.
I am not trying to display all nodes of the current logged in user but of the user associated with the profile that is being viewed.

I have tried to use contextual filters of the Views module (and using a path with arguments), but the *Author uid* context will always refer to the logged in user rather than to the user, whose profile is being viewed. I have trying to fiddle with the Relationship option of the Views module without success.

So my first step would be to create a View which displays nodes of a user in relation to his profile page-URL (I suppose).
Second step would be to display that view as a tab in the profile overview.

I do not necessarily have to use profile2 and views. I just thought it would be the most adequate way to deal with the issue.

Thank you in advance for every help.

/edit: a similar question I have found on stackexchange [earlier](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102135/how-to-display-all-nodes-by-user-on-his-profile-page), but it has not been resolved it seems.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The other question has an accepted answer.   Why do you think it has not been resolved?

Comment: Insofar as there is no solution provided on how to implement that view as tab in the user profile. I now have urls to get the accordant view, but that does not give me tabs in user profiles ... (especially since tabs usually dont have their own url)